# Store SHA256 in sql-server

Tags: sql-server, security, sha256

First of all sorry about my level of ignorance about security so I hope this won't be a silly question. I need to develop a payment gateway and I've just realized I need to store an SHA256 key for authentication operations. So, I think  I can store that key in a configuration row inside a one row SqlServer table, so here is my question: do i need to take any measure such as encrypt the key or take any action in order to protect this information? Thanks in advance,

Comment: I think your question would have better chances at http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have asked yet, thanks

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use (Standard, Enterprise / 2014, 2012) ?

Comment: It could use several versions; the min version is SqlServer 2005 Express Edition